# Calling DialogFragment from DialogFragment, ClassCastException in getActivity()

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment1 (it is called by MyFragmentActivity) in my App with date and time field. When user clicks on them the DatePickerFragment and TimePickerFragment appears. They also extend DialogFragments. I want to returm values from them to DailogFragment1 as usual:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        EditDateDialogListener activity = (EditDateDialogListener) getActivity();
        activity.onFinishDateDialog(day, month, year);

}
```

(before I implemented all as usual)

```
public interface EditDateDialogListener{
void onFinishDateDialog(int day, int month,int year);
}
```

and in DialogFragment1 that implements EditDateDialogListener:

```
public void onFinishDateDialog(int day, int month, int year){
this.mDay=day;
this.mMonth=month;
this.mYear=year;
updateDateDisplay();
```

}
But I have got a runtime Error 
    12-01 20:03:52.018: E/AndroidRuntime(756): java.lang.ClassCastException: MyFragmentActivity cannot be cast to DatePickerFragment$EditDateDialogListener

I understand that this is dialogfragment not activity, but how can I call to it right way? GetWHAT?
Thank you for your time.

UPD: my MyFragmentActivity do not implement EditDateDialogListener, because I do not need this Date there, but in DialogFragment1.

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
```

Comment: Is EditDateDialogListener your own implementation? I can't see a mention of it in the API.

Comment: aha, it is implemented by my DialogFragment1..

Comment: Post how you define `MyFragmentActivity`. The line `public class MyFragmentActivity ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this q. like this:
in  MyFragmentActivity there is a tag:

```
DialogFragment dlg = MyFragmentActivity.newInstance(p1,p11, p2, p3);
dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DataFragmentTag");
```

and in DatePickerFragment:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    EditDateDialogListener handler = (EditDateDialogListener) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DataFragmentTag");
    handler.onFinishDateDialog(day, month, year);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Addition**

> my MyFragmentActivity do not implement EditDateDialogListener, because I do not need this Date there, but in DialogFragment1.

I see. Then DailogFragment1 must implement EditDateDialogListener as described below and you need to change `onDateSet()` to use [`getParentFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29):

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    EditDateDialogListener listener = (EditDateDialogListener) getParentFragment();
    listener.onFinishDateDialog(day, month, year);
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

I assume that you are trying to do something like [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents) in the Developer's Guides.

This error means that `MyFragmentActivity` does not implement your custom `EditDateDialogListener`. Simply change this:

```
public class MyFragementActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

To this:

```
public class MyFragementActivity extends FragmentActivity implements EditDateDialogListener {
//                                             Add this:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And override your listener's `onFinishDateDialog()` callback.

---

All together change `MyFragmentActivity`:

```
public class MyFragementActivity extends FragmentActivity implements EditDateDialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onFinishDateDialog(int day, int month, int year) {
        // Do something
    }
    // The rest of your MyFragmentActivity code here
}
```

With the change above this line in `DatePickerFragment`:

```
EditDateDialogListener activity = (EditDateDialogListener) getActivity();  // It works!
```

Won't throw any more exceptions.

Comment: oh... do you want to say that I should send Date to the MyFragmentActivity first and then from there pass this Date to FragmentDialog1?

Comment: I read an Example, yes that is I did, it works fine with the activity and DialogFragment. But they say there "but often you'll want to deliver the event to the activity or FRAGMENT that opened the dialog. " So there can be a "host fragment" to pass data directly to it, but I cannot fint a way to reach it directly, without activity-reseller.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I did update my post too, so it is clear that I did all this, but with the DialogFragment, because I no need to pass date to the MainActivity, I need this to host DialogFragment1.

Comment: compilation error here, The method getParentFragment() is undefined for the type DatePickerFragment

Comment: may be I should write something in DialogFragment1 for it to know that it is parent? :)

Comment: Oops `getParentFragment()` was added in API 17, you'll have to find it another way like with the FragmentManager or creating a reference yourself.

Comment: oh... what a pity! I use 14. How to create this reference..?

Comment: When you create `DailogFragment1` give it an id and try: `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dailog1)`.